# Cloudberry & SageAccouting Access to the folder is denied

Tags: backup, cloudberry

When Backing up the Sage Accounting Data folder Cloud berry says that access is denied. Yet the user has access.

The work around currently is to run a Robocopy script before the backup to copy the folder to another location then it is backed up and after backup runs a script to delete the copied folder.

While this works its not the "right" solution.

Has anyone any ideas on why only cloud berry would not have access to Sage Accounting Data files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you run Cloudberry Backup service under the right service account?

By default it uses Local System account.

Comment: Thank you, this resolved the issue. Also note to Future Troubleshooters, Service Account information is Case Sensitive.